# Google Cloud Paltform: Personal credentials in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was working with service accounts and got this at one point when I was trying out logging in with a person account, but I'm not sure what it means in terms of what exactly is being stored or what the ramifications mean. What credentials are stored on the VM and where are they stored? Suppose I want to go back and remove those credentials, how would I do this?

```
You are running on a Google Compute Engine virtual machine.
It is recommended that you use service accounts for authentication.

You can run:

  $ gcloud config set account ``ACCOUNT''

to switch accounts if necessary.

Your credentials may be visible to others with access to this
virtual machine. Are you sure you want to authenticate with
your personal account?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it depends on your config during installation, but by default it saves your credentials under `~/.config/gcloud`.

On there, it depends on the products you are using and how are you authenticating. The regular ones are in `credentials.db`. If you `cat` that file, you'll be able to see your [refresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), and that is the dangerous part.

Some other credentials can be found under `~/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/`, and if you're using the `gsutil` tool, you might find also credentials under `~/.gsutil`.

If you want to remove them all, feel free to `rm` both the `~/.config/gcloud` and `~/.gsutil` folders.

Furthermore, using the flag `--verbosity debug` when running an operation will display where it's saving your tokens (flag `-DD` for `gsutil`).

The code for the Google Cloud SDK is mainly written in (a pretty good) python, so you can always spend a little time reading the code of the tool if you are curious.

I'm personally using a hacked version of the `gcloud` tool to modify some auth params that I didn't like in the default version and that were hard-coded (`sed` to the rescue!), and I'm not even a python dev, so you can guess how easy to understand is the code.

The default installation of the SDK is in `~/google-cloud-sdk/`, so the bulk of the code for `gcloud` can be found under `~/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/`.